# PHP URL Inquiry

Tags: php, url

How exactly would I get the URL with PHP so I could do this:

profile.php?username=Blah

How would I get the 'Blah' from the username= part by using PHP?

Comment: the question is vague. What do you mean by "get the URL"? Are you asking how to get the username when profile.php is the executed PHP Script or do you want to know how to parse the URL string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP there are global variables that hold parameters passed on the url or by posting a form. Some of this variables are $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST, $_FILES.

```
<?php
$username = $_GET['username']
echo $username;
```

You can read more on superglobal variables here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: Would this work without posting username via a form? So anyone can just type in ?username=random_username ?

Comment: Yes. $_GET is for URL parameters. $_POST is for form parameters and you can use $_REQUEST for both.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `$_GET` variable

`$username = $_GET['username'];`

Comment: Again, would this work without posting username via a form so I can just type in ?username=random_username ?

Answer (score 1):

The special [`$_GET`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) variable is an array containing all parameters passed in the URL, like `username` in your example.

You can access them using the `$_GET['parameter_name']` syntax:

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
```

See the manual page of this variable: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_GET['username']` to retrieve the username parameter value from the URL
For more on this visit: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp